# How to add Wordpress JS Script Links

Tags: customization, themes, javascript

Hi I do have a code here from my HTML. I just dont know/forgot on how to link scripts in wordpress...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js1.js?1"><\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2.js?1"></script>
```

Comment: Read the codex?

Comment: <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory_uri()` is better practice. That said, you should be properly enqueuing (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your scripts, and should have no reason to call jQuery from Google at all, as jQuery is bundled with WP.